# How can I make the hover effect work when leaving the whole container

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

When I hover over the content div, the effect works fine. But when I move my mouse outside of the .parent div, the image does not fade out. There is also an issue when the transition takes place, that you see a flash of a broken image icon. Is there an easy way to fix these issues?

This code can be saved to an html file and run exactly as is.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
        <style>
            .parent {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                background-color: black;
                position: relative;
            }
            .child {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                object-fit: cover;
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                opacity: 0;
            }
            .content {
                height: 20vh;
                position: relative;
                z-index: 1;
                border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
            }
            .content h3 {
                position: relative;
                margin: 10px;
                color: white;
                text-align: center;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="parent">
            <img class="child" src="">
            <div class="content" data-imgurl="https://loremflickr.com/320/240?lock=30976">
                <h3>Title</h3>
            </div>
            <img class="child" src="">
            <div class="content" data-imgurl="https://loremflickr.com/320/240/paris,girl/all?lock=30976">
                <h3>Title</h3>
            </div>
            <img class="child" src="">
            <div class="content" data-imgurl="https://loremflickr.com/320/240/dog?lock=30976">
                <h3>Title</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-/JqT3SQfawRcv/BIHPThkBvs0OEvtFFmqPF/lYI/Cxo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>
            $('.content').hover(
                function() {
                    var dataImg = $(this).data('imgurl');
                    $(".child").finish().attr("src", dataImg).animate({
                        opacity: 1
                    }, 400);
                },
                function() {
                    $(".child").finish().animate({
                        opacity: 0
                    }, 400).attr("src", '');
                }
            );
        </script>
    
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

When I hover over the content div, the effect works fine. But when I move my mouse outside of the .parent div, the image does not fade out. There is also an issue when the transition takes place, that you see a flash of a broken image icon. Is there an easy way to fix these issues?

This code can be saved to an html file and run exactly as is.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <style>
        .parent {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: black;
            position: relative;
        }
        .child {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            object-fit: cover;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            opacity: 0;
        }
        .content {
            height: 20vh;
            position: relative;
            z-index: 1;
            border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
        }
        .content h3 {
            position: relative;
            margin: 10px;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="parent">
        <img class="child" src="">
        <div class="content" data-imgurl="https://loremflickr.com/320/240?lock=30976">
            <h3>Title</h3>
        </div>
        <img class="child" src="">
        <div class="content" data-imgurl="https://loremflickr.com/320/240/paris,girl/all?lock=30976">
            <h3>Title</h3>
        </div>
        <img class="child" src="">
        <div class="content" data-imgurl="https://loremflickr.com/320/240/dog?lock=30976">
            <h3>Title</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-/JqT3SQfawRcv/BIHPThkBvs0OEvtFFmqPF/lYI/Cxo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        $('.content').hover(
            function() {
                var dataImg = $(this).data('imgurl');
                $(".child").finish().attr("src", dataImg).animate({
                    opacity: 1
                }, 400);
            },
            function() {
                $(".child").finish().animate({
                    opacity: 0
                }, 400).attr("src", '');
            }
        );
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `.attr("src", '')` is the cause of the broken image icon

Comment: @imvain2 would you suggest a placeholder image instead, the same colour as the background perhaps?

Comment: Like @imvain2 stated, when un-hovering the actual HTML is changing to `<img src ...` Without the src attribute in the `<img` tag it will display broken image .. A placeholder is a good start

Comment: Sure thing. I don't think that it the reason that the fade effect doesn't happen when leaving the parent div though?

Comment: Instead of changing opacity with `animate` .. I would try  `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()`

Comment: Also setting the src to '' TIED to the end of the .animate call does not ensure it will WAIT for the animate to complete before setting the src to '' .. So the image assuredly is disappearing instantly while the fade effect is "working"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of referencing .child, I used `$(this).prev()` to reference the previous element of the content element that was triggering the animation on hover.

Also I removed the `.attr("src", '')` so it won't have a broken image.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
        <style>
            .parent {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                background-color: black;
                position: relative;
            }
            .child {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                object-fit: cover;
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                opacity: 0;
            }
            .content {
                height: 20vh;
                position: relative;
                z-index: 1;
                border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
            }
            .content h3 {
                position: relative;
                margin: 10px;
                color: white;
                text-align: center;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="parent">
            <img class="child" src="">
            <div class="content" data-imgurl="https://loremflickr.com/320/240?lock=30976">
                <h3>Title</h3>
            </div>
            <img class="child" src="">
            <div class="content" data-imgurl="https://loremflickr.com/320/240/paris,girl/all?lock=30976">
                <h3>Title</h3>
            </div>
            <img class="child" src="">
            <div class="content" data-imgurl="https://loremflickr.com/320/240/dog?lock=30976">
                <h3>Title</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-/JqT3SQfawRcv/BIHPThkBvs0OEvtFFmqPF/lYI/Cxo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>
            $('.content').hover(
                function() {
                    var dataImg = $(this).data('imgurl');
                    $(this).prev().finish().attr("src", dataImg).animate({
                        opacity: 1
                    }, 400);
                },
                function() {
                     $(this).prev().finish().animate({
                        opacity: 0
                    }, 400);
                }
            );
        </script>
    
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: This is fantastic! Are you able to perhaps tell me why using .prev works so much better?

Comment: @user10980228 when you use `.child` as the selector, you are targeting ALL `.child` elements. When you use `$(this).prev()` you are targeting ONLY the child element closest to the content that is being hovered over.

Answer (score 1):

You animation is working alright, just set the same image as background, since you're setting the opacity to 0, it simply won't be displayed (no need to do `.attr('src', '')`)

```js
$('.content').hover(
  function() {
    var dataImg = $(this).data('imgurl');
    $(".child").finish().attr("src", dataImg).animate({
      opacity: 1
    }, 400);
  },
  function() {
    var dataImg = $(this).data('imgurl');
    $(".child").finish().animate({
      opacity: 0
    }, 400).attr("src", dataImg);
  }
);
```

```css
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.content {
  height: 20vh;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

.content h3 {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img class="child" src="">
  <div class="content" data-imgurl="https://loremflickr.com/320/240?lock=30976">
    <h3>Title</h3>
  </div>
  <img class="child" src="">
  <div class="content" data-imgurl="https://loremflickr.com/320/240/paris,girl/all?lock=30976">
    <h3>Title</h3>
  </div>
  <img class="child" src="">
  <div class="content" data-imgurl="https://loremflickr.com/320/240/dog?lock=30976">
    <h3>Title</h3>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-/JqT3SQfawRcv/BIHPThkBvs0OEvtFFmqPF/lYI/Cxo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```